# Determining bone lengths when importing using Assimp

Tags: animation, assimp

I am trying to load and render some rigged models using Assimp 3.1.1
So I have the aiBone's identified in the hierarchy of aiNode's.
For each aiBone, I have its transformation (TRS) w.r.t. to the parent.

My question is, how can I determine the length of each bone?
Assuming a connected skeleton, this is not a problem for most of the bones, except for the leaf bones. 
Assuming I have the following skeleton structure:
b0 --> b1 --> b2
with b0 being the root bone and b2 being the leaf bone. How can I know the length of b2 (since I only have its transformation w.r.t. b1)?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar difficulty, don't suppose you resolved this?

Answer (score 1):

So, after a little further digging.. 
ISTM that there isn't any implicit way of knowing where leaf bones should terminate.

The following code comments are referenced from the [Ogre3D wiki](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Skeleton%20Debugger) (it's not assimp, but we're talking about the same problem here).

```
if(numChildren == 0)
{
    // There are no children, but we should still represent the bone
    // Creates a bone of length 1 for leaf bones (bones without children)
    // ...
}
```

I suppose you could consider trying to calculate the length of a leaf bone, by calculating the distance from the bone to the edge of the mesh that you're rendering.. though that might be more trouble than its worth.

Answer (score 1):

Even though most SDKs and game engines define a skeleton as having bones, that's incorrect. It actually has **joints**. The bones are the implied connections between joints. When you look at it this way, you realize that all bones have a length and there is no bone extending past leaf joints.

Replacing your example with joints:

```
J0 ---B0---> J1 ---B1---> J2
```

B0 is the bone between J0 and J1, and B1 is the bone between J1 and J2.